# I am looking for a function $f(x,y)$ that is close to $1$ when $(x,y)$ is close to $(n,0)$ but $f(x,0)=0$

Tags: functions

I am looking for a function $f(x,y)\in[0,1]$ (probably not continuous) such that

1. if $x=n$, then $f(x,y)$ increases as $y\to0$ but $f(x,0)=0$;
2. if $y=\epsilon>0$, then $f(x,y)$ increases as $x\to n$;
3. decreases a lot when $x$ decreases a little;
4. decreases when $y$ increases.

Here $n$ is a fixed non-negative integer and I wanted to find the function $f(x,y)$ that fulfills those conditions. For simplicity "a lot" means "exponentially" and "a little" means linearly.

What I came with is $$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x}{ny}.$$ The issue with this is that $f(x,y)\notin[0,1]$ and $f(x,0)$ is not defined and it does not decrease a lot when $x$ decreases a little.

Comment: Are those just some conditions you gave yourself and you wanted to find a function that fulfils that or how did you come up with those conditions? Also what does "a lot" and "a little" mean mathematically? What is $n$? A specific number or should this be true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Also your function should not be continuous right? Otherwise the first condition is a bit difficult as you somehow need to start at $0$ for $y=0$ but then need to decrease until $x=n$

Comment: $n$ is fixed non-negative integer. Yes it is me who created those conditions and I wanted to find the function that fulfills them. We can say for simplicity "a lot" means "exponentially" and "a little" means linearly.

Comment: Yes, no problem if the function is not continuous.

Comment: Okay, condition 4 and 1 are somewhat contradictionary. If the function decreases when $y$ increases but $f(n,0)=0$ and $f(n, \epsilon)$ > 0, then $f(n, .)$ is increasing from $0$ to $\epsilon$ at some point